# Issues Running CodeIgniter from CLI

Tags: php, codeigniter, command-line-interface

I've followed the directions [here](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/cli.html) to run codeigniter from the cli, but I'm not having any luck getting it to run. PHP is in my path, but when I run

```
php index.php tools message
```

Nothing happens. If I try

```
php index.php/tools/message
```

I get "Could not open input file: index.php/tools/message."

If I run php -v on my cli I get

```
PHP 5.3.24 (cli) (built: Apr 10 2013 18:32:42)
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
```

So, it has cli support. Any idea on what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those methods didn't work for me, so I wound up using

```
curl <full url to function>
```

Answer (score 1):

i run the cron job using this

```
/path/tosite/index.php memberController memberFunct
```

In your case

```
/path/tosite/index.php tools message
```

for you case
for more details read this
https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/cli.html#what

Complete Line is:

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php /path/tosite/index.php memberController genFunction  /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: try this      wget api.example.com/index.php/controller/function

Comment: I'm not trying it on the server yet, I'm just trying to get it to work on my machine.

Comment: I got it working with the below solution. Thank you so much for taking the time to help me out even though I wasn't able to implement your solution!